# Connecting to Microsoft Teams through non-interactive powershell script

Tags: azure, powershell, microsoft-teams

I am trying to write an azure function in PowerShell to connect to a Microsoft Teams account:

```
using namespace System.Net

# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)

# Write to the Azure Functions log stream.
Write-Host "Running teams account setup."

[string]$userName = 'xxx'
[string]$userPassword = 'xxx'
[securestring]$secStringPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $userPassword -AsPlainText -Force
Write-Host ($secStringPassword | Format-Table | Out-String)
[pscredential]$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($userName, $secStringPassword)
Write-Host ($credentials | Format-Table | Out-String)
Connect-MicrosoftTeams -Credential $credentials
```

The error message I'm getting is essentially:
`ERROR: password_required_for_managed_user: Password is required for managed user`

I read that it might be necessary to replace `-Credentials` with `-Identity`, but I can't find any documentation on how to implement that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just noticed that you are using Azure Function, I am not quite sure the root reason here, but I did some test on my side and the PowerShell function with code below works for me perfectly:

```
using namespace System.Net

# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)

$username = "<user Name>"
$passwd = "<PassWord>"

$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $passwd -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $secpasswd)
Connect-MicrosoftTeams -Credential $cred

#try to get a team name to test if connect to teams successfully
$team = get-team -groupID '0d06e74e-08e0-4ef6-9bb5-3113ca735407'
$body = $team.DisplayName


# Associate values to output bindings by calling 'Push-OutputBinding'.
Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
    StatusCode = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
    Body = $body
})
```

Content of `requirements.psd1`:

```
@{
    # For latest supported version, go to 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az'. 
    'Az' = '5.*'
    'MicrosoftTeams' = '1.1.9-preview'
}
```

Test result:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, your suggestion is producing the same error message. Here's a gist of the full log: https://gist.github.com/danielbecker/14d50e63ee84126baa222d861c4ef06a

Answer (score 0):

Azure function utilize the Powershell core.

Looks like there is a known issue with regards to the Powershell core which has been reported to the product group and it is already worked.

Reference :
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/office-docs-powershell/issues/5950

Reading further, I don't see ETA on this. The thread is expected to be updated once there is a fix.

Coming back to the `-identity` , it is just a switch parameter (you need not pass anything) which logs in using managed service identity in the current environment. I doubt this might be applicable in your case.  The below would be the implementation if you would like to try.

```
Connect-MicrosoftTeams -Identity
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use applications + certificate with connect-microsoftteams. See details at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/teams/connect-microsoftteams?view=teams-ps#example-4-connect-to-microsoftteams-using-a-certificate-thumbprint.

Comment: Please provide more detail then a link to another website. Doing so is a good practice in case the link changes in the future.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34559098)

Answer (score -1):

To solve this issue, we have a third option of storing encrypted credentials to a file on the computer. The PowerShell script uses the encrypted password from the file to create a credential object.
please go through below links.
[link1](https://4sysops.com/archives/scheduling-powershell-scripts-with-usernames-and-encrypted-passwords/)
[Link2](https://practical365.com/blog/saving-credentials-for-office-365-powershell-scripts-and-scheduled-tasks/)

Comment: The question is not about a script running on a computer but as an Azure function.